# ValidationAttribute for Specific Values Only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validationattribute

Is there `ValidationAttribute` in `.net` for closed set of values?

For instance in the code below, only "a", "b" and "c" are the valid values for `StringType` property, and 1, 10, 100 are the only allowed values for `IntType`

```
  public record RequestModel
  {
     [StringOptions("a", "b", "c")
     public string StringType{get; init;}


     [IntOptions(1, 10, 100)
     public string IntType{get; init;}
  }
```

10x.

Comment: What .NET version do you use? Starting .NET 8 there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.allowedvaluesattribute?view=net-8.0. Also, if it's only restricted set of values, consider using enums.

Comment: @AlekseiPetrov 10x. - please convert your comment to an answer, and I mark it as one

Answer (score 1):

For Older versions there is no built-in `ValidationAttribute` that allows a property to have a closed set of specific values directly in the way you're describing with `StringOptions` or `IntOptions`

Create a Ccustom validation attributes

```
public class StringOptionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _options;

    public StringOptionsAttribute(params string[] options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;  

        string stringValue = value as string;
        return _options.Contains(stringValue);
    }
}

public class IntOptionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int[] _options;

    public IntOptionsAttribute(params int[] options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;  

        if (value is int intValue)
        {
            return _options.Contains(intValue);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public record RequestModel
{
    [StringOptions("a", "b", "c")]
    public string StringType { get; init; }

    [IntOptions(1, 10, 100)]
    public int IntType { get; init; }
}
```

For better validation rules use [Fluent Validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html#) it provides lot of features.